# Can't wait to go to Japan

Tags: english-to-japanese

I want to translate : I can't wait to go to Japan / I can't wait to be in Japan.
I mean I already planed to go and I'm going there in two weeks. I'm wondering how to express this in Japanese.

Is " 日本に行くのが待ち遠しい " correct ?
Is " 日本に行くのを楽しみにしています" better ?

Also, does it sound friendly and excited ?

Would it be correct to say : 日本に行くのが待てなーい？

Thanks for reading my post. :)

Answer (score 5):

There is an exact set phrase to translate "cannot wait to/for": **待ちきれない**. 待ち遠しい is as much good but its grammatical equivalent is "be a long time coming".

> 日本に行くのが待ちきれない！

would sound friendly as well as excited.

> 日本に行くのが待てなーい

is... um... yes, perfectly natural, providing you're a teenage girl.

For the meaning of -きれる, please see: [Compound verb with きれる](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/33938/7810)